# Two UI tableview cells in one controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, multiple-tables

I have two custom table views with two custom cells.

```
self.detourTblView.delegate = self
self.detourTblView.dataSource = self
self.dropDownLuggageTblView.delegate = self
self.dropDownLuggageTblView.dataSource = self
```

And this is how I fill data.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.dropDownLuggageTblView {
        let luggage_cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "luggage_cell", for: indexPath) as! LuggageCell

        luggage_cell.luggageTypeTxt.text = luggageTypeList[indexPath.row]
        return luggage_cell

    }

    if tableView == self.detourTblView {
        let detour_cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detour_cell", for: indexPath) as! DetourCell
        detour_cell.selectionTime.text = detourSelectionList[indexPath.row]
        return detour_cell        
    }
    return cell    
}
```

This gives me following error,
Terminating app due to uncaught exception

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier luggage_cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack:

But I have given both identifiers in the storyboard.
Why is this occur?

Comment: Are you sure you gave the exact identifier `luggage_cell` to your prototype cell in `dropDownLuggageTblView` in `Storyboard`? It looks like a typo problem to me.

Comment: `I have given both identifiers in the storyboard` - Obviously not if you chose that answer. To make this question more valuable to others, you should explain why you thought you had put the identifiers in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason of the error is that no cell in your storyboard or in xib file have the identifier : "luggage_cell"** 
This is an example on how to add an identifier with UICollectionView and a Prototype Cell
[image]